# Not Sure It's a bug on Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, date, google-chrome

I got about javascript console to display date problem using Chrome v7.0517.41 browser(not sure if it is a bug) and OS is WinXP SP3.

In javascript console, i type ***console.log(new Date());*** 
then display :

> Sat Oct 30 2010 22:49:57 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) //it's now on local time

I change system time to +1 month and type command to display:

> Tue Nov 30 2010 22:50:20 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) //it's correct time

**BUT**,when change month to March and type command again:

> Tue Nov 30 2010 22:50:40 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)//NOT change

So,i must **CLOSE** Chrome Browser and retry display date:

> Tue Mar 30 2010 22:51:13 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)  //it's correct time **AFTER** closed Chrome Browser

Why appear this problem? It's a bug on Chrome Browser? Thx u...

Comment: Does this have something to do with programming? It seems to have to do with changing your system date.

Comment: only change system date.Can u help me test Chrome Browser?

Comment: Have you tested this in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with Google Chrome browser v7.0517.41 on Mac OSX 10.5.8 works just fine.

However on Windows XP it is working exactly as you have documented it above and seems to be a bug.

Firefox version 3.6.10 was tested on both Operating Systems and it gave a consistent output.

Answer (score 0):

In your first test, you went into the future from `October 2010` to `November 2010`. Chrome's interpreter takes that without a cinch, as expected.

In your second test, you went back into the past from `November 2010` to `March 2010`. I suspect WinXP Chrome has difficulties dealing with a current date that suddenly becomes *earlier than the start date of its own process*, and goes [la la la I can't hear you](http://www.google.com/images?q=la+la+la+i+can%27t+hear+you&hl=en&biw=1106&bih=645) about that until you restart it.